# How to create a JsArray as JavaScriptObject

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

i need a JavaScriptObject what contains a JsArray and a String.
That JsArray should have all functionalities like the normal GWT`s JsArray like push(), pop() etc.
but how to create that?
I have created something what i mean but it doesnt work

```
public class Tour extends JavaScriptObject {

protected Tour() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static Tour getInstance(){
    return JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
}

public final native void setTourName(String name)/*-{
    this.name = name;
}-*/;

public final native String getTourName()/*-{
    return this.name;
}-*/;

public final native JsArray<JavaScriptObject> getArray() /*-{
    return this.array;
}-*/;

public final native void setJsArray(JsArray<JavaScriptObject> array)/*-{
    this.array = array;
}-*/;

public final native void push(JavaScriptObject obj)/*-{
    this.array.push(obj);
}-*/;

public final native int getLength()/*-{
    this.array.length;
}-*/;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Tour extends JavaScriptObject {

    protected Tour() {
    }

    public static Tour getInstance() {
        return getInstance(null, null);
    }

    public static Tour getInstance(String name) {
        return getInstance(name, null);
    }

    public static native Tour getInstance(String name, JsArray<JavaScriptObject> array) /*-{
        return {
            name : name,
            array : array || []
        };
    }-*/;

    // the rest of your class stays untouched...

    public final native void setTourName(String name)/*-{
        this.name = name;
    }-*/;

    public final native String getTourName()/*-{
        return this.name;
    }-*/;

    public final native JsArray<JavaScriptObject> getArray() /*-{
        return this.array;
    }-*/;

    public final native void setJsArray(JsArray<JavaScriptObject> array)/*-{
        this.array = array;
    }-*/;

    public final native void push(JavaScriptObject obj)/*-{
        this.array.push(obj);
    }-*/;

    public final native int getLength()/*-{
        this.array.length;
    }-*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JsArray is *(by extending it)* a JavaScriptObject by itself.
The JsArray can however not hold the Java/GWT based String objects, due to that these aren't real JavaScript Strings.

To let the JsArray contain Strings, use the JsArrayString. This one handles strings at native level.

> JsArrayString jas = JsArrayString.createArray().cast();

Comment: i dont mean that i mean a own javascriptobject overlay class.
I have edited the question.